# Get a button click to populate form fields of the most recent point collected

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a form where upon Saving/Adding The Next Point, a popup appears upon clicking SaveAddNext asking the user if they would like to populate the new fields based on the old. This works perfectly.

However, I'm having trouble implementing this into a button form. I require this situation as well if a user decides to quit the form, re-enter it, add a new point, and wants to autopopulate.

Bits of working SaveAddNext Code :

```
Public Sub New(ByVal Record As Feature, 
               ByVal previousRecord As Till_NonTillStation, 
               ByVal SurficialType As enumTillTypes)

    MyBase.New(Record, Constants.COL_TILL_CREATED_BY, 
               Constants.COL_TILL_CREATION_DATE, Constants.COL_TILL_EDITED_BY, 
               Constants.COL_TILL_EDIT_DATE, 
               DirectCast(previousRecord.Geometry, Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.MapPoint))

    If MessageBox.Show("Autopopulate fields from last point collected?", "Record Autopopulation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) = vbYes Then

        Me.EXPOSURE_TYPE = previousRecord.EXPOSURE_TYPE
        Me.EXPOSURE_HEIGHT = previousRecord.EXPOSURE_HEIGHT
        Me.UNIT_THICKNESS = previousRecord.UNIT_THICKNESS
        Me.UNIT_TYPE = previousRecord.UNIT_TYPE
        Me.TILL_FACIES = previousRecord.TILL_FACIES
        Me.PERCENT_CLAY = previousRecord.PERCENT_CLAY
        Me.FIRST_LITHOFACIES_TYPE = previousRecord.FIRST_LITHOFACIES_TYPE
        Me.CONSISTENCY = previousRecord.CONSISTENCY
        Me.COLOUR = previousRecord.COLOUR
        Me.CLAST_PROVIDENCE = previousRecord.CLAST_PROVIDENCE
        Me.CLAST_ROUNDNESS = previousRecord.CLAST_ROUNDNESS
        Me.NOTES = previousRecord.NOTES

    End If
```

Button Code so far. I make a call to the Sub New, it makes it down to the popup, but doesn't read any data. I'm not sure how to refer to the data :

```
Private Sub btnAutopopulate_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnAutopopulate.Click

    previousRecord = New Till_NonTillStation(Constants.TillNonTillFeatureTable.CreateFeature, 
                                             _feature, enumTillTypes.Non_Till)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET Sub new is the **constructor**  of an object.

When you click on **btnAutopopulate**, you are creating a **New**
an instance of  `Till_NonTillStation`, therefore any previous data stored in other instances 
are not available.

Do not use(call) **Sub New**(constructor) .  Create a different function or method to 
set previous data.

Here is my suggestion based on your last comments:

1: Create global variables to store your data: for example Use

> Public Shared EXPOSURE_TYPE as string
>   This is different than using 
>   Me.EXPOSURE_TYPE 
>   which depends on an instance of the Form.

Above is the easy way, however many programmers frown upon using global variables, so a better way is to create a class(outside the Form) and store your data inside it.

Comment: Hm - I see. Creating a new sub UsePreviousData() that btnAutopopulate_Click will use, but I still seem to hit the same wall. Unsure how to refer to the previous entry's data within this function / without using the sub new.

Comment: This is only the first step to use the Button. Question is what you do after that. Where the previous data are stored? How about to try to store previous data in a Collection or a class or even an array and then using them.

Comment: Make sure you are not calling Sub new in your code. I will update my answer.